# Problem connect to some websites using DSL

Tags: firefox, internet, connection

No problems when connecting to Google, GitHub using Firefox in DSL connection.

However, when I try to browse [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org) or [support.mozilla.org](http://support.mozilla.org), the browser keep showing Connecting... in the tab title and the page is blank.

I have tried other browsers such as chrome and chromium but the problems still not solved.

I also tried to ping coffeescript.org and the ping works fine, returning packet with time=2xx ms

When I switch to Wifi connection, I can connect to those websites.

How to fix this problem in DSL connection?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using pppoe-setup instead of nm-connection-editor to setup DSL